# How can I make my website redirect to another based on a cookie with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do this with .htaccess. So what I did was set a cookie named "domain" with the website I'm redirecting to. In my .htaccess file I have this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} domain=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

I got that code from a Google search. It's supposed to reditect http://mywebsite.com/something to http://someotherwebsite.com/something. But it's not working. Any tips?

Edit: I still haven't been able to get it to work. A temporary solution I'm using is using PHP to get the cookie value and redirect that way.

Comment: Just to clarify, the cookie belongs to mywebsite.com, right?

Comment: Yes. I've checked with Javascript and PHP. As a temporary solution I'm using PHP to redirect but I want to do it this way because I think it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn on [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) on a fairly high level and see whether that provides a clue.